# Why is OpenAPI-generated Spring server unable to parse an unwrapped XML array with sibling elements?

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI in my Spring Boot project and I have the below partial spec for OpenAPI to parse some XML data, including an unwrapped array which is element `KYCInfo`:

```yaml
CallbackRequestData:
  type: object
  xml:
    namespace: '<some_namespace>'
  properties:
    TransID:
      type: string
    TransTime:
      type: string
    TransAmount:
      type: number
      format: double
    ...
    KYCInfo:
      type: array
      xml:
        wrapped: false
      items:
        type: object
        required:
          - KYCName
          - KYCValue
        properties:
          KYCName:
            type: string
          KYCValue:
            type: string
```

The XML to be parsed is as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:C2BPaymentValidationRequest xmlns:ns1="http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment">
            <TransID>ABCDEFGIJKL</TransID>
            <TransTime>20210926113918</TransTime>
            ...
            <TransAmount>1.00</TransAmount>
            <KYCInfo>
                <KYCName>[Personal Details][First Name]</KYCName>
                <KYCValue>John</KYCValue>
            </KYCInfo>
            <KYCInfo>
                <KYCName>[Personal Details][Last Name]</KYCName>
                <KYCValue>Doe</KYCValue>
            </KYCInfo>
        </ns1:C2BPaymentValidationRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have generated the API interfaces for Spring Boot using `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` v5.2.1. My issue is that when I send the XML above to the API generated by the above, am getting the below error, showing the XML mapper is unable to convert the XML array into a POJO:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `CallbackRequestDataKYCInfo` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[Personal Details][First Name]'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `CallbackRequestDataKYCInfo` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('[Personal Details][First Name]')
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 14, column: 44] (through reference chain: C2bValidationRequest["Body"]->C2bValidationRequestBody["C2BPaymentValidationRequest"]->C2BCallbackRequestData["KYCInfo"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])]
```

NB: full Package names have been removed. Is there any reason its failing or what am I missing? Note that I have no control over the XML, am consuming a remote 3rd-party API.

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question - but OpenAPI is not really suitable for SOAP APIs. It was designed with REST APIs in mind.

Comment: @Helen am aware of that, but am working on a project that acts as a proxy between XML and JSON, and this is the most popular way I could find to have a single API act as an intermediary for both via a specification